# Certain files created from MemoryStream are corrupt

Tags: c#, filestream, memorystream

I have code that passes a list of objects containing the filename and binary data from the db to a loop that creates all the files. The problem that I have is the code below executes and appears to create the files correctly (filename & size is as expected) however, most files are "corrupt" when opened. The file types vary from images (jpg/png) to Word documents, Powerpoint presentations and PDF files. What is strange is that PDF files work perfectly, everything else is "corrupt"

My code is below (`attachment` is the object in the loop, the path is already created at this stage)

```
if(Directory.Exists(attachmentPath))
{
    string absolutePath = attachmentPath + "\\importfiles\\" + parentfolders + "\\";

    // no need to check if it exists as it will ignore if it does
    Directory.CreateDirectory(absolutePath);
    absolutePath += filename;
    try
    {
        byte[] byteStream = null;
        object objSave = null;

        objSave = attachment.Image;
        BinaryFormatter tmpBinF = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream tmpMemStrm = new MemoryStream();
        tmpBinF.Serialize(tmpMemStrm, objSave);
        byteStream = tmpMemStrm.ToArray();

        // Delete the file if it exists.
        if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
        {
            File.Delete(absolutePath);
        }

        // Create the file.
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(absolutePath))
        {
            fs.Write(byteStream, 0, byteStream.Length);
            fs.Dispose();
        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exceptions.Text += ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've used tips from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) and followed [this](https://jwcooney.com/2013/06/20/net-write-a-file-to-disk-from-db/) tutorial but can't figure out why this is happening.

**Thanks go to Amy for pointing out the issue with my approach**, if anyone needs it, here's my updated code taking her answer into account. I've also extended it to add a log record on a table in the DB for later use.

```
if (Directory.Exists(attachmentPath))
{
    // build path from the parts
    string absolutePath = attachmentPath + "\\importfiles\\" + parentfolders + "\\";

    // no need to check if it exists as it will ignore if it does
    Directory.CreateDirectory(absolutePath);
    absolutePath += filename;
    byte[] file = attachment.Image;
    try
    {
        // Delete the file if it exists.
        if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
        {
            File.Delete(absolutePath);
        }

        // Create the file.
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(absolutePath))
        {
            fs.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
        }

        // start logging to the database

        // add the Stored procedure
        string SP = "sp_add_attachment";

        // create the connection & command objects
        MySqlConnection myConnection1 = new MySqlConnection(WPConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd1;
        try
        {
            // open the connection
            myConnection1.Open(); 

            cmd1 = myConnection1.CreateCommand();

            // assign the stored procedure string to the command
            cmd1.CommandText = SP;

            // define the command type
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // pass the parameters to the Store Procedure
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttachmentID", attachment.ID);
            cmd1.Parameters["@AttachmentID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subpath", parentfolders);
            cmd1.Parameters["@subpath"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", filename);
            cmd1.Parameters["@filename"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            // execute the command 
            int output = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // close the connection
            myConnection1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exceptions.Text += "MySQL Exception when logging:" + ex.ToString();
        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exceptions.Text += ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might not need the last `fs.Dispose()` since it's implied by the usage of `using`. I doubt it's the cause of the issue though.

Comment: Thanks @HoriaComan - I'll remove that since it's not necessary, pretty obvious when you point it out! :)

Comment: The object you're trying to write is `attachment.Image` no? What's its format? How do you know for sure it is a proper jpg/png to begin with, and not just a matrix of pixels, for example?

Comment: The object is a BLOB from a CMS database. It is "proper" as I can see the output when I browse the site (using the same database). What I don't understand is why PDF files work but everything else seems corrupted. What's different about creating a PDF file as opposed to a Word Document?

Comment: Is this the [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) you're using? That seems to transform an in memory object into a byte stream. But the in memory representation of the object might be quite different than what the PNG/jpeg standards want. Even if the object itself is just an array of bytes, containing a properly encoded jpeg image. What type does objSave actually have?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. I used that from the second tutorial I'd referenced. The class uses a `byte` type for the `attacment.image` that is assigned to the `objSave`. I acknowledge I may be doing things completely wrong here, my experience is more in PHP and I'm finding my way around C#. I'm happy to follow another guide or technique

Comment: I don't think using the BinaryFormatter is appropriate.  If `attachment.Image` is a byte array, simply write it to the filestream.  Forget the memory stream and the binary formatter entirely.

Comment: @Amy that worked first try. Thank you!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using the BinaryFormatter is appropriate. If `attachment.Image` is a byte array, simply write it to the filestream. Forget the memory stream and the binary formatter entirely.

The Binary Formatter class is used to serialize a .Net class into a byte array.  You already have a byte array though, so that step is not needed and is the source of your problem.  Using the binary formatter would be appropriate only if the same binary formatter was used to create the blobs in the database.  But you're storing files, not .Net objects, so it isn't useful here.

I'm not sure why PDFs would load when other files won't.  You'd have to inspect the file using a hex editor to see what changed.

Comment: Yes, the PDF files working was the weirdest aspect of this issue but your answer was perfect. Thank you

Comment: It might be that the byte stream produced is simply four bytes of length and then the content of the array which is a serialized PDF document. Might be that PDF readers are very lax in their input handling and they know to skip some byes before finding a roper PDF document.